# Node.js Accessing outer class from inner class

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, circular-dependency

So I have concerns about accessing a class from within a class. The pseudocode below is not identical but is similar to the structure I have.

```
class Parent{
    constructor(name, children){
        this.name = name
        this.children = children;
    }

    AddChild(Child){
        this.children.push(Child);
    }
    
    RemoveChild(Child){
        this.children = this.children.filter(child => child != Child);
    }
}

class Child{
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    cycle(){
        setInterval(() => {
            if(this.age >= 18){
                //Remove this child from parent
            }
            this.age++;
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

For this example, I need to remove `child` from `parent` when the child is above the age of 18. However, I cannot access the parent from within the Child. I have tried referancing the parent as a property of child but have never used circular referancing before and dont know how safe it is to do so.

My questions are as follows:

1. For this example, what is a way of accessing the parent function `RemoveChild()` from the child class.
2. Is circular referancing a safe partise to use for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your axample, as you pointed out, you for sure need a reference to the `Parent` in the `Child` class, otherwise you cannot call a method of it, because you don't have an instance of it.

About circular references, you also pointed out that it can be something dangerous. If a `Child` can live without a `Parent`, you should always check when accessing its parent field that is a set to a value (not null).

The biggest problem about circular references are memory leaks. A garbage collector (for language having one, such as JS) or a smart pointer (for languages like C++ or Rust, not having garbage collection) basically looks if the object is still referenced somewhere to know when to free its memory. If a `Parent` references a `Child` and vice-versa, but nowhere else any variable references them, they are left alone in the wild, being never freed because each one of them is referenced by the other, but any other place doesn't. So you cannot access and use them anymore, but your program still has the memory allocated for them. Memory leaks can make a computer run out of memory on the long term. This is the main danger to care about.

Comment: And I assume if I had, for the example above, x amount of `children` which all have the same `parent`, it would store a referance to a single `parent` rather than storing x amount of parents.

Comment: As long as you create a single `Parent` then give it to each `Child` constructor, a unique `Parent` object will be created. This is because JS hides object behind references, so when you give an object to a function, the value is not copied but it is given by reference. Each time you will interact with the `Parent`in `Child` classes, it will refer to the one you gave in the constructor, which may be the same.